# Identification of injective linear maps with image and inclusion

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces, submanifold

Suppose $S$ is an immersed submanifold of $M$. Let $\iota: S\hookrightarrow M$ be the inclusion map. Since it is an immersion, at each $p\in S$, $\iota_{*}:T_pS\rightarrow T_pM$ is injective. Hence we identify $T_pS$ with its image under $\iota_{*}$ . **Under this identification, $\iota_{*}$ is the inclusion map**

Recall that elements in $T_pM$ are defined by derivation on the space of germs of smooth functions at $p$.

I am not quite sure I am completely convinced with the bolded statement. May someone elaborate?

Comment: What is your definition of tangent space, and the pullforward?

Comment: @ArcticChar space of derivation, and derivations are defined as germs of smooth functions.

Comment: Wait, isn't that the definition of an immersed submanifold, that $\iota_*$ is injective?

Comment: We know that $T_pS$ not live inside $T_pM$ but $\iota_*(T_pS) \subseteq T_pM$. Clearly we have inclusion map $i :\iota_*(T_pS) \hookrightarrow T_pM$. Now lets write $T_pS$ for $\iota_*(T_pS)$. So $i : T_pS \hookrightarrow T_pM$ is an inclusion map where its image is exactly like $\iota_*$.

Comment: Basically we pretend $T_pS$ live inside $T_pM$ by renaming it as $\iota_*(T_pS)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your question about the bold statement does not really have to do with manifolds or geometry. It is just a general mathematical thing.

When you have an injective function $f \colon A \to B$ between sets (they don't have to be manifolds or tangent spaces, they can just be any sets), then since $f$ is "one-to-one", there is a bijection between $A$ and the image of $f$. It is common in math when there is a bijection to say $A$ when you really mean the image $f(A)$.

This is part of what bijections are all about. They allow you to identify two sets.